# Spring DI Unsatisfied dependency expressed

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, servlets, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="user" class="com.pomkine.pottyauth.domain.User"/>
    <bean id="userdao" class="com.pomkine.pottyauth.persistance.GaeUserDao"/>
    <bean id="userservice" class="com.pomkine.pottyauth.service.UserServiceImpl">
        <constructor-arg ref="userdao"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class RosterController {

    private UserService userService;

    @Inject
    public RosterController(UserService userService){
        this.userService=userService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/userRoster"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showRosterPage(Map<String,Object> model){
        model.put("users",userService.getAllUsers());
        return "userRoster";
    }
}
```

So I want UserService to be injected into my controller. But I'm getting the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rosterController' defined in file [S:\Coding\Idea_workspace\pottyAuth\target\pottyAuth-1.0\WEB-INF\classes\com\pomkine\pottyauth\mvc\RosterController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.pomkine.pottyauth.service.UserService]: : No matching bean of type [com.pomkine.pottyauth.service.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

Here is my UserServiceImpl class:

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private UserDao dao;



    public UserServiceImpl(UserDao dao){
        this.dao=dao;
    }
    @Override
    public User getUser(User user) {
        return dao.getUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
         dao.addUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    public List getAllUsers() {
        return dao.getAllUsers();
    }
}
```

So I'm expecting Spring container to create UserServiceImlp bean and inject it into RosterController. But it seems that it cannot find UserServiceImpl bean.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

UserServiceImpl is not implementing UserService

edit:
also I can't see

```
<context:component-scan  base-package="">
```

Is this whole Spring configuration?

Answer (score 0):

It means Spring couldnt find any bean of type `UserService`. Check your `UserServiceImpl` class.
Wondering why you are using both XML and annotation based approach to define beans? It will good if you stick to either of them.

---

**EDIT:**
Add `@Component` annotation to `UserServiceImpl`. So that Spring will come to know that it should create a object of `UserServiceImpl`

```
@Component
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService  
{
.....  
}
```

and as @pawelccb have mentioned use

```
<context:component-scan  base-package="your.base.package">
```

in Spring config file.
Check this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-scanning-components/) for details.

Comment: Yep, I see. But why it cannot find? I defined my beans in config file and want my UserServiceImpl class to be enjected into RosterController. So I used @Inject. Btw how can I define my controller bean in applicationContext.xml?